# Generate network out traffic at specified rate

Tags: c++, algorithm, networking

I am trying to inject network traffic into a cluster for the purposes of an experiment. Specifically, on each node in a cluster I want to read in a configuration file of the following type

```
Rate         Time
100Mbps       5 min
50Mbps        10 min
...
```

The above example means that I want to generate TCP outbound traffic at the rate of 100 Mbps for the first 5 mins, 50 Mbps for the next 10 min and so on.

My networks knowledge is a little fuzzy at this point - any pointers to help me get started would be great!

Comment: What kind of a data would you need to generate? TCP, UDP? IP? Random Ethernet frames? Just some random garbage?

Comment: I need to generate TCP packets. Sorry for the vagueness.